# Is @ valid in any part of the zone file?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

e.g. can I do

```
subdomain IN CNAME @
```

in a zone file? or is it only valid in the beginning of a record? e.g

```
@ IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx -all"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` is legal both as an "owner name" (i.e. the name of a zone file entry) and as "rdata" (i.e. the contents of a DNS entry), but **only** as a standalone token.

What you cannot do is `<label>.@` - there's no need because `<label>` on its own with no trailing dot will implicitly append the current value of `@` (aka `$ORIGIN`).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/). They did not say explicitly whether it is allowed or not to have `@` at the end in your DNS record. You can try it yourself and see if it works!

**EDIT:**

It seems legal to have at the end. I found [an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file#File_format) on Wikipedia.